# How to sort and filter a field which is in other indices in elasticsearch?

Tags: java, sorting, elasticsearch, nosql

For example, I have a index named 'student':

```
{
    "id": "100",
    "name": "Frank"
}
```

then there is another index named 'grade':

```
{
    "id": "1"
    "score": 95,
    "studentId": "100"
}
```

how can I use one query to get a page of student and sort by score?
Can I use join query to search these two indices like MySQL?
This is what I want to get:

```
{
    "id": "100",
    "name": "Frank",
    "score": "95"
},
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no. Gotta normalize your data since joins are not possible in ES. More at elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relations.html